# Minecraft: Beacon with Haste / Haste II is not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have followed every step to make the beacon work, yet it still not working.

1. Build Beacon Pyramid (I did minimum in my single player world and a full on my realm)
2. Select Buff(s)
3. Add E/I/D/G payment
4. Activate

I am getting the buff icon and timer but it is not effecting my mining at all, its the same with and without the buff.

I have never used a haste beacon before, I got it in my realms world and it did not work then in `1.15.1` or now in `1.15.2`. Yet I know it should work as I have seen the hermits in hermitcraft using it.

I did use a [datapack with custom villager trades](https://vanillatweaks.net/picker/datapacks/) to get the beacon in my realm.

I used a [wither skeleton head dropper datapack](https://www.planetminecraft.com/data-pack/wither-skeleton-skulls-higher-drop-chance/) in my single player world.

Edit: Here are some screenshots:
[image: Small Beacon]
[image: Pick of Power]
[image: Beacon Active]
[image: Have Effect]
[image: Still not working]

I don't understand why it does not work. Unless its a bad file of something like that.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot with your beacons buff selected?

Comment: What tool are you using to mine what? It's sometimes a bit hard to notice the difference. Haste is especially useful when you it gives you the final bit of speed to cross the "insta-mining" boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between mining Efficiency V without Haste I and with Haste I for **stone**. For instant-mining it you need Efficiency V with **Haste II**.
There is a table for it on [minecraft gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Haste#Instant_mining)

Answer (score 0):

There is a gap in the speed of mining - if your block breaking speed would be shorter than 8 game ticks (0.4s) but higher than 1 game tick, it's set to 8 game ticks - therefore Efficiency V pickaxe + Haste I doesn't help against stone. It does though, against terracotta and basalt. Additionally, you can insta-mine stone with Haste I and Efficiency V *gold* pick.

You can watch the attached Ilmango's video for a thorough, in-depth analysis of the mechanics and overview mining speeds of various tools, including the upcoming Netherite.